# Adonis JS 5: How do I make a validator class for both HTTP requests and plain data validation?

Tags: validation, adonis.js

I have a TaskValidator class in Adonis that handles validation. It works fine for normal HTTP requests in my controller. However, I also want it to be able to handle validation where there is no http request, i.e. no ctx.

I need to get some data that will either come from the request.body() or from the data object when not using http request.

Relevant bit of validator here:

```
import { schema, rules, CustomMessages } from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Validator'
import type { HttpContextContract } from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/HttpContext'

export default class TaskValidator {
  constructor(protected ctx: HttpContextContract) {}

  public schema = schema.create({
    name: schema.string({ trim: true }, [
      rules.maxLength(255),
      rules.unique({
        table: 'tasks',
        column: 'name',
        whereNot: { id: this.ctx.params?.id ?? 0 },
        where: {
          matter_id: this.ctx.request.body().matter_id?? -1,
          deadline: this.ctx.request.body().deadline?? -1,
        },
      }),
    ]),
```

Here is the method I would like to use the validator with.

```
public static async createTask(
        event: Event,
        matter: Matter,
        rule: Rule,
        taskDeadline: DateTime,
        workflow: Workflow,
        workflowDeadline: DateTime,
        workflowStep: Workflowstep
      ) {
        const task = new Task()
        task.name = workflowStep.name
        task.deadline = taskDeadline
        task.workflowDeadline = workflowDeadline
        task.workflowstepId = workflowStep.id
        task.sequence = workflowStep.sequence
        task.ruleId = rule.id
        task.workflowId = workflow.id
        task.eventId = event.id
        task.matterId = matter.id
        task.isActive = true
        task.status = 'open'
        task.actorId = null
    
        //Validate task
    
        const taskValidator = new TaskValidator({} as HttpContextContract)
    
        // const validatedTask = await validator.validate({
        //   schema: taskValidator.schema,
        //   data: task,
        //   messages: taskValidator.messages,
        // })
    
        await Promise.resolve(async (task: Task) => {
          await validator
            .validate({
              schema: taskValidator.schema,
              data: task,
              messages: taskValidator.messages,
            })
            .then(() => {
              Task.create(task)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error(error.messages)
            })
        })
      }
```

Have run into a mental block and can't seem to think of a way around it. Apart from making another validator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a DTO.

A DTO, or "Data Transfer Object", is a design pattern used in programming to transfer data between different parts of a software system. Its main objective is to encapsulate data and send it from one place to another efficiently and coherently.

I leave you an example for adonis JS

```
import { validator, schema, rules } from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Validator'
    
    export default class MyDTO {
      readonly name: string
    
      private constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name
      }
    
      public static async create(data: object) {
        const payload = await validator.validate({
          schema: this.rules(),
          data: data,
        })
    
        return new MyDTO(payload.name)
      }
    
      public static rules() {
        return schema.create({
          name: schema.string()
        })
      }
    }
```

Then you just have to call it where you need it or simply pass the required object

```
const dto = await MyDTO.create(request.body());

const dto = await MyDTO.create({name: "test"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I just structured the data to validate to look like it comes from an http request. I split the validation into another function that I can call from wherever.

```
    public static async validateTask(task: Task) {
        const ctx = {} as HttpContextContract
    
        ctx.request = {
          body: () => {
            return task
          },
        } as any
    
        ctx.params = {
          id: task.id,
        } as any
    
        const taskValidator = new TaskValidator(ctx as HttpContextContract)
    
        const validation: Partial<Task> = await validator.validate({
          schema: taskValidator.schema,
          data: task,
          messages: taskValidator.messages,
        })
    
        return validation
      }
    }
```